# Dynamically added partial view with DatePicker not working as expected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Partial view (_SubView) which is having multiple controls

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
            buttonImage:   "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Icons/Calendar.png")" , //"../../Content/Images/Icons/Calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        //altFormat: 'yymm',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            $(this).datepicker();
            $(this).change();
        }
        });
    $(".datepicker").datepicker().keydown(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //   TAB: 9
        //  LEFT: 37
        //    UP: 38
        // RIGHT: 39
        //  DOWN: 40
        //             IE        OTHER
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        DatePickerKeyDownEvent($(this).val(), code);

        if (currentDate != null) { $(this).datepicker("setDate", currentDate); }

        });
});
</script>
@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("form")
{
// A set of labels and dropdown controls
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MaturityDate, new { @class = "datepicker", @title = "Enter Maturity Date",id="date-picker" })
}
```

In main view, I have a button "Add New Item". When ever user clicks on Add New Item, _SubView will be added to the main view dynamically.

Question:

When ever user dynamically add multiple  partial views to the main view and try to change individual maturity date , date is changing only in the initially added partial view. 
But when user tries to change the date using keydown event, respective date control is changing correctly without any issues.

Can anyone help me where exactly I am doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is happening because you set the input id to "date-picker", 
remove `id="date-picker"`